# Nautilus closes

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and when I use nautilus and switch to another program whose window is maximized, the nautilus screen disappears. Maybe related, my desktop shows duplicate icons of anything in it, but only one is "selectable". Hope someone can help me, and the question is not a duplicate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What question would this be a duplicate of? Also, have you read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/595777/unity-unable-to-bring-programs-to-foreground) and does it answer your question? Please edit your question some more and explain your problem in depth. "when I use nautilus and switch to another program whose window is maximized, the nautilus screen disappears." Does the program close, or does it just minimize?

Comment: @James , thanks a lot, I try to  see if the nautilus was hidden  but, this morning the equipment seems to work fine, and also the desktop has only one icon per item.
If the trouble shows again I check if nautilus is hidden or closed

Comment: Alright. Glad its working again!